# A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, catalina

I am having issue with starting `tomcat 7.0 server` for `localhost`. (**eclipse indigo, Java**) . Below is the error message and the server fails to start in **45ms**. Could someone explain what I am getting this error?

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JDAExt]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JDAExt]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> CrystalReportViewerHandler in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3183)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1302)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1239)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Dec 22, 2015 8:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:646)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Dec 22, 2015 8:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:646)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Dec 22, 2015 8:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4312 ms
```

Thank you. I was able to fix web.xml but now I get a different error.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class requisite.servlet.RequisiteHomeServletContextListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at requisite.servlet.RequisiteHomeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RequisiteHomeServletContextListener.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at devon.core.log.appender.LFileAppender.write(Unknown Source)
    at devon.core.log.LLogger.write(Unknown Source)
    at devon.core.log.LLogger.println(Unknown Source)
    at devonframework.service.security.requisite.impl.LErrorLogger.println(Unknown Source)
    at requisite.rule.RuleMapper.getRuleDirectory(RuleMapper.java:72)
    at requisite.rule.RuleMapper.refresh(RuleMapper.java:81)
    at requisite.rule.RuleMapper.<clinit>(RuleMapper.java:40)
    ... 11 more
Dec 22, 2015 10:14:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Comment: Could you share your web.xml?

Comment: in web.xml, url-pattern was incorrect like you said. it didn't begin with '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  Invalid <url-pattern> CrystalReportViewerHandler in servlet mapping
```

Your web.xml contains an invalid mapping for servlet CrystalReportViewerHandler .

Correct that and you'll be fine. If you don't kno how to correct: Post the web.xml snipplet.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix the web.xml but now I get the following error.

Answer (score 0):

It is about this line;

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> CrystalReportViewerHandler in servlet mapping
```

In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:

> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form 
>     http://host:port//. In this case the path info is ’/’ and
>     the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only

If you share **web.xml**, we can give specific answers.

For reference please look [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) and this [Servlet Configuration](http://jweavers.com/posts/How_to_configure_Servlet_file_in_web.xml_configuration_file.php).

Comment: Thank you I fixed the web xml now but I am getting a new error.